# wrong data in PHP session

Tags: php, email, session, soap

**I have the following setup for a webshop:**
When a user logs in, a script is called via AJAX, which validates the user data against a SOAP-Webservice
and returns the user data. While the user is logged in, user data is saved in the PHP Session. User data
is only retrieved by SOAP and not stored by the shop. I use the default PHP Session handler.
When a user places an order, a confirmation email is sent to the users' address.
The amount of traffic on the site is moderate, about 100 orders per day.

**I have the following bug:**
Roughly once in three months an email is sent to the wrong address. Other data from the session in the 
email body (ex.customerNo) are correct but apparently the value of the email address is wrong.

**Here is what I found out so far:**
Each time this happened, the users whose addresses got mixed up, had logged in at the exact same time (+- 2 seconds).
I unsuccessfully tried  to reproduce this by logging in with two different users at the same time and
comparing the Session data.

Assuming the data returned from the SOAP-Webservice is correct, what could cause this problem?

EDIT: Here are the code snippets for writing and reading form the Session en the email bit the code is out of context, I left out bit in between:

EDIT2:Removed the code snippets as the problem turned out to be a caching error in the SOAP-Service implementation called to retrieve email data.

Comment: This will probably be very tough to tell without seeing some code, especially the E-Mail bit...

Comment: It's hard to tell without actual code. How exactly do you set the data in the session, what does the e-mail part look like, and have you tried logging the data, so you can figure it out?

Comment: I added the code for writing an reading the session and for the email sender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Each time this happened, the users whose addresses got mixed up, had logged in at the exact same time (+- 2 seconds). I unsuccessfully tried to reproduce this by logging in with two different users at the same time and comparing the Session data.

The problem you describe has most likely arisen because of overzealous caching and / or problems with data leakage at one end or the other.

I think its very unlikely that the sessions are getting confused at the PHP end - however there may be problems with session aliasing in your code. It would have been helpful to know if your PHP instances are running as forked processes or threads.

The right way to test if the problem is on the remote server (which is significantly more likely of the remote server uses threading) is to script the operation - NOT use a browser - and run the test hundreds of times with different pairs of credentials - not just once.

Comment: Thanks! How do i know whether my  PHP instances are running as forked processes or threads?