# Php session data is returning wrong value

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, caching, server

I have an application that i built in php 7 with the code-igniter framework and my problem is with the session data , storing and retrieving session data works fine , but occasionally when two people log in at close intervals , the session data for the first user is also retrieved for the second user, searched through the site , saw something similar here ([wrong data in PHP session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305070/wrong-data-in-php-session))  that suggested that it might be a caching issue (my site uses nginx for caching) , but no concrete solutions were suggested. Any suggestions or Ideas will be appreciated.

Edit : Here is the section of my login library for authentication

```
public function login_account($email,$password)
    {
       $db = "db";
       $data = array("login_mail" => sha1($email));
       $query_result = $this->CI->m_eauth->get_login_password($data,$db);

       $hash_password ="";

        foreach($query_result->result_array() as $value)
        {
         $hash_password = $value['hash_password'];
         $site_name = $value['hash_name'];
         $account_type = $value['account_type'];
         $site_match_id = $value['site_match_id'];
         $site_levels = $value['levels'];
         $site_roles = $value['roles'];
        }

        if(password_verify($password, $hash_password)){
            // Success!
            $session_data = array(
              "site_id"=>$site_match_id,
              "site_email"=>$email,
              "site_name"=>$site_name,
              "site_avatar"=>md5($email).".jpg",
              "site_type"=>$account_type,
              "site_levels"=>$site_levels,
              "site_roles"=>$site_roles
             );

            $this->CI->session->set_userdata($session_data);

              return "successful";
        }
        else{
            // Invalid credentials
            return "unsuccessful";
        }
    }
```

Let me add that the login works fine and individual sessions work just fine. But every now and then the problem i described happens , and i'ts quite confusing as i don't know where to look.

Comment: could you show your login code ?

Answer (score -1):

There's no real way to sugar coat this, sessions aren't some magical part of PHP that you enable you to just call `session_start()` and go about your day. If your application is leaking sessions then you haven't secured it properly and you need to fix it.

Session security is a pretty big deal, given that a hijacked session basically gives an attacker total access to someone else's account.

I would recommend you read the official PHP [session docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.session.security.management.php) and also consider implementing the [Nginx userid module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_userid_module.html) as an additional measure for identifying users.